# connection java jdbc sqlite path of data base file

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a following problem with Java SQLite.

In command:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Michal\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Logowanie\\src\\logowanie\\uzytkownicyfaktur.db");
```

I have a path to local data base file.

but if I will write it in following way:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:uzytkownicyfaktur.db");
```

It shows an error: No such table

I have both files: file of class and file of data base in the same package.

I don't know a reason of this error.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You need a "//" in there,

"jdbc:sqlite://C:\Users\Michal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Logowanie\src\logowanie\uzytkownicyfaktur.db"

Answer (score 0):

Without a path, SQLite will try to open the database file in the current path (which is somewhat unpredictable).

If the database file does not exist, SQLite will automatically create an empty one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:");

shows errors:
1.) No such table: 'Users'
2.) NullPointerException